# How to prove that a curve is an injective regular parameterization?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametrization

I have the above assignment:
Prove that the curve $σ:\Bbb R → \Bbb R^2$ given by 
$$σ(t)=\left(\frac{t}{1+t^4}, \frac{t}{1+t^2}\right),$$ 
is an injective regular parameterization, but not a homeomorphism with its
image.

I have found the derivative and prove that it does not equal to zero so it is a regular parameterization but I don't know what to do next.

Can someone help?

Comment: do you already plot? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%5Bt%2F%281%2Bt%5E4%29%2C+t%2F%281%2Bt%5E2%29%5D%2C+0%3Ct%3C9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once one get the plot, one sees that the trouble is at the $\sigma(0)$ position.

There, is impossible to find an open set  $U$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that ${\rm im}\sigma\cap U$ is an open arc containing $\sigma(0)$, i.e. there $\sigma$ isn't locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can we prove that the curve is injective?

Comment: Ok, let me think a bit more but it begins... suppose that $(a/(1+a^4),a/(1+a^2))=(b/(1+b^4),b/(1+b^2))$ and this would imply $a=b$

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any good to you now but it may help others.

The parametrization is injective as $ \forall t \in $ $\Bbb R$  as $\exists$ a unique x(t) , y(t) in $\Bbb R^{2}$ where $ x(t) = \frac{t}{1+t^{4}} $ , $ y(t) = \frac{t}{1+t^{2}} $ this can be seen by plotting the function.

This question can be found in Curves and Surfaces by Abate and Tovena problem 1.1