Show that a curve is injective
Let $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\alpha(t) = (\frac{t}{1+t^4},\frac{t}{1+t^2})$ is a simple curve.
I tried studying the functions $\frac{t}{1+t^4}$ and $\frac{t}{1+t^2}$ but I concluded none of these is injective so the curve itself could have self-intersections. I also tried to study $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4}$ but concluded nothing.
Plotting the curve on desmos looks like it is indeed injective, but I'm facing some difficulties to show it. Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

Also asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3756455/42969 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1502190/42969, but none of those answers has a rigorous proof of the injectivity.

@MartinR I've read those threads, but as you said they really don't answer the question. Because once I proved it's injective I have no problem to show that it's not an homeomorphism, the problem is indeed I can't show it's a simple curve

Define $f(t)=\frac t{1+t^2}$ and $g(t)=\frac t{1+t^4}.$
If $t_1\neq t_2,$ with $f(t_1)=f(t_2),$ show that $t_1t_2=1.$
If also $g(t_1)=g(t_2),$ then $t_1(1+t_2^4)=t_2(1+t_1^4).$ Rearranging, we get:
$$t_1-t_2=t_1t_2(t_1-t_2)(t_1^2+t_1t_2+t_2^2)$$
Then using $t_1-t_2\neq0$ and $t_1t_2=1,$ this reduces to:
$$1=1+t_1^2+t_2^2$$
This is only possible if $t_1=t_2=0,$ which contradicts the assumption that $_1\neq t_2.$

Nice
For the first part (if use $x$ and $y$): $xy^2+x=x^2y+y$ so $x(1-xy)-y(1-xy)=0$ which has solutions when $x=y$ or $xy=1$. Thank you a lot
